# scala regex pattern giving matcherror

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string

```
val path = "/bigdatahdfs/datalake/raw/lum/creditriskreporting/iffcollateral/year=2017/month=05/approach=firb/basel=3/version_partition=8/vFirbtestCollateralBaselIIIData_201705_8_20170620.txt.gz"
```

the pattern

```
.*version_partition=(\d+)(.*)
```

is working as expected in regex101.com.

Requirement is to extract two strings. one is "8" (exactly after version_partition=)and another is "/vFirbtestCollateralBaselIIIData_201705_8_20170620.txt.gz"

In scala REPL the same pattern is giving scala.MatchError. I am new in using regular expressions. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Please help me here.

scala code is

```
val P = """.*version_partition=(\d+)(.*)""".r

val P(ver,fileName) = path;
```

I have tried with /g and /m flag also. It didn't work.

Comment: Your Regex has an white space at the end. If you get rid of that it works

Comment: The `.*` at the start of the Regex is useless. You can leave it away.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works : https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Xz1Y0Ze/0

You don't need /g and /m flag.

- /g ==>  Perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping
  after the first match)
- /m ==>  Perform multiline matching

code :

```
val path = "/bigdatahdfs/datalake/raw/lum/creditriskreporting/iffcollateral/year=2017/month=05/approach=firb/basel=3/version_partition=8/vFirbtestCollateralBaselIIIData_201705_8_20170620.txt.gz"

val P = """.*version_partition=(\d+)(.*)""".r

val P(ver,fileName) = path;

println(ver)
println(fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it using a match like this:

```
val path = "/bigdatahdfs/datalake/raw/lum/creditriskreporting/iffcollateral/year=2017/month=05/approach=firb/basel=3/version_partition=8/vFirbtestCollateralBaselIIIData_201705_8_20170620.txt.gz"
val P = """.*version_partition=(\d+)(.*)""".r

path match {
  case P(a,b) ⇒ 
    println(a)
    println(b)
}
```

[Test](http://rextester.com/XBFW72534)

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally added a white space at the end.

https://regex101.com/r/FLkZEu/2

The `.*` at the beginning of the regex is useless